# .ebextension is not working in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I build the war I can see .ebextension folder as shown below.
myapp.war
|------ .ebextensions
|------META-INF
|------org
|------WEB-INF

**.ebextensions has two files**
configuration.properties and 01do.config

**Content of 01do.config**
container_commands:
copy-config:
command: "cp .ebextensions/configuration.properties /etc/tomcat7/configuration.properties"

Command given in the config is not getting executed and there are no logs for this in cfn-init.log.

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation is important.

```
container_commands:
  copy-config:
    command: "cp .ebextensions/configuration.properties /etc/tomcat7/configuration.properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

in gradle projects or other you need include .ebextension in your final package.

for gradle

```
for gradle 
<code>

bootJar {
    from('./.ebextensions') { into '.ebextensions' }
}
or

bootWar {
    from('./.ebextensions') { into '.ebextensions' }
}
</code>
```

[Clean way of adding .ebextensions to Spring Boot Jar using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207803/clean-way-of-adding-ebextensions-to-spring-boot-jar-using-gradle)