# Clean way of adding .ebextensions to Spring Boot Jar using Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, ebextensions

Is there a clean way of adding additional root folders to a Spring Boot Jar file generated using the default bootRepackage. In my case I need the .ebextenions folder for AWS beanstalk.

I know I can hack it -- for example add another task after bootRepackage to unzip, repackage (again), and re-zip.  Is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks

.. the 2 ways that I've tried (that don't work) :

```
jar {
    from('src/main/ebextensions') {
        into('ebextensions')
    }
}

bootRepackage {
    from('src/main/ebextensions') {
        into('ebextensions')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still working on deploying Spring Boot to EBS myself...

I think the folder has to be called `.ebextensions` (notice the leading dot). So you would say `into('./.ebextensions')` instead of `into('ebextensions')`.

Alternatively, you might try uploading a ZIP file containing your JAR and your `.ebextensions` folder:

```
task zip(type: Zip, dependsOn: bootRepackage) {
    from ('./.ebextensions') {
        into '.ebextensions'
    }
    from (jar.outputs.files) {
        into '.'
    }
    destinationDir project.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have my .ebextensions folder in my Spring Boot project's root folder, and I copy-pasted the code above into my build.gradle, but I don't see my .ebextensions folder show up in my jar file's root folder. What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: It's a hidden folder and may not be displayed right away.

Answer (score 7):

For Spring Boot 2 (Gradle) if `.ebextensions` is located at the root of your project, use the following task:

```
bootJar {
    from('./.ebextensions') { into '.ebextensions' }
}
```

or

```
bootWar {
    from('./.ebextensions') { into '.ebextensions' }
}
```

This way Gradle will copy `.ebextensions` into the root of the application package.

But if you prefer [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), move `.ebextensions` folder inside `src/main/resources`. The content of resources directory is packaged automatically in `/BOOT-INF/classes/` (no scripting required). And the `.ebextensions` directory will be discovered by EB deployment scripts when unpacked.

Comment: (SO poll) please leave a comment here: which of 2 solutions did you pick?

Comment: Newer platform "Amazon Linux 2" does not parse files inside Jar anymore  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html

Answer (score 2):

With Grails 3, I use `gradle clean dist` to create a .zip file containing a .war for EB distribution, and use a `Procfile` to describe the Spring Boot command line. An `.ebextensions` folder is in the base directory of my project, and `projectName` and `projectVersion` are variables defined in the `build.gradle` file:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    from war.outputs.files
    from "src/staging/Procfile" // this file allows us to control how ElasticBeanstalk starts up our app on its Java SE platform
    from('./.ebextensions') {
        into '.ebextensions'
    }
    rename { String fileName ->
        if (fileName == "${projectName}-${projectVersion}.war".toString()) {
            fileName.replace("${projectName}-${projectVersion}", "application")
        } else {
            fileName
        }
    }
}
dist.dependsOn assemble
```

where the contents of the `Procfile` in `src/staging` looks like this:

```
web: java -jar application.war
```

Answer (score 2):

If you move your src/main/ebextensions folder to src/main/resources/.ebextensions, it will be automatically copied by the jar task to the root of the .jar (along with any other files in /resources), where EBS expects it, without any additional scripting.

That's about as clean as you can get!

Answer (score 2):

I have my .ebextensions at the root of my project.  This seems to work for me.

war {
  from ('./.ebextensions') {
    into '.ebextensions'
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

**Sept 2021**

I tried to add the .ebextensions folder in my jar but is seems elastic beanstalk doesn't like it anymore.

Instead, I had to create a zip file with the jar and the .ebextensions folder inside.

Like this

```
~/myapp.zip
|-- myapp.jar
|-- .ebextensions/
```

[Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)

Here is my gradle kts code:

```
val jarFilename = "myapp.jar"

val packageZip by tasks.register<Zip>("packageZip") {
    dependsOn("bootJar")
    archiveFileName.set("myapp.zip")
    destinationDirectory.set(layout.buildDirectory.dir("libs"))

    from("$buildDir/libs/$jarFilename")

    from("../.ebextensions") {
        into(".ebextensions")
    }
    from("../.platform") {
        into(".platform")
    }
}

tasks.register<Delete>("cleanLibs") {
    delete("$buildDir/libs/")
}

tasks.named<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    dependsOn("cleanLibs")

    this.archiveFileName.set(jarFilename)

    finalizedBy(packageZip)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As all the supplied answers didn't fix the problem, I found another solution to this problem. Just add the .ebextensions to the list of artifacts which come out of the buildspec.yml

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - app.jar
    - .ebextensions/**/*
```